# Why would Wordpress throw a 404 error on a POST form submit in one template, but not in another?

Tags: wordpress, php

I've developed a php mail() function for custom forms in a Wordpress theme. It's just a normal form that gets submitted to itself (with an empty `action` attribute). In functions.php, I'm including `inc\mail.php`, which checks whether POST data is present, and if so, it runs the function. In the end, the function sends an email via php's `mail()` and returns true.

This works perfectly for a single post that has a custom post type (not "post" or "page"), but when I try to use the same script on a normal Wordpress "page", it runs the function as well (and sends the email), **but then it throws a 404 error.** The URL in the browser address bar is unchanged (shows the permalink of the page), but it doesn't seem to find the page.

Then, if I refresh the page (without sending POST data again), i.e. by clicking on the browser address bar and hitting Enter), **it shows the right page again as usual.**

I'm stumped. Why would it do that?

Edit: found the solution here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11749/why-when-i-submit-a-form-in-wordpress-it-loads-a-404-page-though-url-is-correct thanks to @DigitalDesignDj's suggestion to look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your function is returning a value for display on the page, but only when it succeeds in sending an email. You need to suppress the output of the function, because I am guessing it happens above wp_head and interferes with the calls that start the template process up.

This is a guess, but go look for that output, it's all I can think of.

You might have better luck asking at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the input - it's a good guess, I thought the same thing at first, but the function is not outputting anything, it's only filling a variable... so I don't think it's a header issue. I'll give the wordpress forum a shot though, good tip :) Thanks!

Comment: DigitalDesignDj, you were right. Wordpress.stack had the answer already: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11749/why-when-i-submit-a-form-in-wordpress-it-loads-a-404-page-though-url-is-correct  -- I'll mark your answer as correct for that. Thanks again!